# How to change heading for all posts in a collection, like Authentication, in Postman?

Tags: postman

Is there a way to change the headings across a collection in postman. Such as a token of Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer, for now, which uses a mix of setGlobalVariable in first test, then ussing {{name}} in the heading. No need for pre-request Script.

So. The first test gets my auth token using means needed. In the "Tests" for that call we set

```
var jd = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("token", jd.token);
```

- "token" is the variable w will use later
- jd.token is what we want passing over

Next in the following calls in the collection, we want to use "token".

[image]
So in the Header, we set {{token}} which is the GlobalVariable set in the first call.

some reference of this

- [add or remove header](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1382)
- [reusing pre-request script](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/882)
- [another request for some means of this](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2050)